# Using two VideoCaptures in openCV to capture the same device

Tags: c++, opencv

If I use `VideoCapture` to get images from the same device like this:

```
    VideoCapture cap1,cap2;
    cap1.open(0);
    cap2.open(0);
    Mat image1,image2;
    cap1 >> image1;
    cap2 >> image2;
```

Will `image1` and `image2` be the same?

Comment: why not just test it? use cb::absdiff on both images and test whether any pixel isn't cv::Vec3b(0,0,0) then the frames are not the same.

Comment: @Micka Do I need to scan the mat to  test whether any pixel isn't cv::Vec3b(0,0,0)?

Comment: you could use cv::inRange instead from (1,1,1) to (255,255,255) and countNonZero on the resulting mask, but you could miss minimal changes then (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0) ;)

Comment: @Micka well, I scanned it and it's not Vec3b(0,0,0) for all pixels. I think the images may be alternant in the stream.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for answering it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open same device on two diferent `VideoCapture` at same time.

Check this:

```
VideoCapture cap1,cap2;
cap1.open(0);
if (!cap1.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera 0 on cap1\n";
}
cap2.open(0);
if (!cap2.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera 0 on cap2\n";
}
```

Probably you get something like this:
Output:

> ERROR! Unable to open camera 0 on cap2

Comment: Are you sure? I tried this but no error occurred. I use openCV 3.0.

Comment: @user7857293 did you check `isOpened` as in my example?

Comment: @user7857293 well you are so lucky, open 2 `VideoCapture` in same device is like selling same house to two different person...

Comment: probably depends on the driver of the device.